# fourier package is not working all of a sudden

Tags: xetex, packages, fourier

All of a sudden (probably after LaTeX upgrade today) the line `\usepackage{fourier}` causes the following compilation error: `! I can’t find file ‘FourierOrns’.` **Hint:** I am using `XeTeX` without changing anything than the upgrade today.

A MWE is:

```
\documentclass[10pt,article]{memoir}
\usepackage{fourier}

\begin{document}

test

\end {document}
```

I tried also what has been suggested below to reinstall the `fourier` package; same problem. [This](https://pastebin.com/raw/5dcBwSYh) is the `.log` file.

Comment: Try: `sudo tlmgr install fourier --reinstall`

Comment: Show a small,  complete example that can be used for tests.

Comment: Just a stab in the dark. Do you happen to have a second, older, version of the fourier package?

Comment: I edited the post to reflect the suggested commented above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latest version of the `fourier` package added a OpenType version of the Fourier Ornament font. Sadly, this font is loaded by font name and not by filename, so XeTeX can not find the font if it is not installed as system font.

The easiest fix is to use LuaLaTeX instead of XeLaTeX or to wait for another update of `fourier` which fixes this issue. If you want to continue using XeLaTeX, you can also help `fontspec` find the right font by creating a `.fontspec` file which maps the name to filenames:

Create a file `FourierOrns.fontspec` [in a directory where TeX can find the file](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-privinst) (e.g. the directory of your LaTeX document or under `~/texmf/tex/latex/`) with the content

```
\defaultfontfeatures[FourierOrns] {
  Extension = .otf,
  UprightFont = *-Regular,
  BoldFont = *-Bold,
  ItalicFont = *-Italic,
  BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic,
}
```

This tells fontspec that the font `FourierOrns` can be found in files named `FourierOrns-Regular.otf`, `FourierOrns-Bold.otf`, etc.

After creating this file, `fourier` works again under XeTeX.

Comment: Wonderful; thanks so much Marcel. Very crisp and up-to-the-point reply. The problem is solved. Regarding `LuaLaTeX` vs. `XeLaTeX`, the former was my choice a couple of years ago. However, since I write both Arabic and English in the same document, `LuaLaTeX` still has some glitches. It did not work with me out of the box like `XeLaTeX`.